# How to emulate or make multiple iSCSI software initiator IQNs on RHEL RedHat 7?

Tags: linux, redhat, storage, iscsi, rhel7

I have 2 Ethernet HBAs with 2 ports each, all 4 ports are connected to iSCSI targets and I can login using iscsiadm command.

But the iSCSI initiator name (IQN) for all 4 ports is one, in /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi

I need to have a separate distinct IQN for each of the 4 ports on the RedHat 7 host. So, 4 IQNs each mapped to one of the ports/ip addresses

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Look in RHEL documentation for section on  "Configuring iSCSI Offload and Interface Binding"